# Best way to hang a weight rack on studs that are 24" on center

Tags: framing

I bought a weight rack that is meant to be hung on studs that are 16" on center. Well the studs in my garage are 24" on center. I was thinking of hanging 2x6 horizontally on the studs with lag screws and then mount the rack to those. Any better way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest hanging 2x8 _horizontally_ instead of _vertically_. The extra depth of the 2x8 will support more weight than a 2x6. You'll want to look at span tables, though, and base your decision on how much weight you're going to actually hang there.

Comment: If the wall is open, adding more studs will not hurt.

Comment: A picture and/or diagram would help.

Comment: I edited the post, I meant horizontally.

Comment: See also: All the questions on hanging TVs in similar situations.

Comment: Impossible to answer this question without knowing the total of all the weights, the largest weight, their distribution on the rack, and the configuration of the rack's mounting brackets.   A picture would help.  Helpful to know why you don't put it on the floor, as It obviously won't be very high.    At my gym they have all kinds of weight racks, the lightest one has a total of  28 pounds on it distributed evenly.  The heaviest, about 1400 pounds, most of it at one end.  The wall mounting options would differ.  Or are you talking about a "rack" style gym that is only stabilized by the wall?

Answer (score 2):

Weight and eccentricity from the wall would also be important information if there were strength values to compare against. Technically you're using wood in torsion instead of the bending of vertically oriented lumber. The National Design Specification (NDS), which is the wood design code behind US building codes, annoyingly has no torsional strength provisions. It basically says "don't do it," but I don't think that this text is actually printed anywhere in it (by not mentioning it, they let the typical building code invocation of "accepted engineering practices" admit other sources for torsion). Err on the side of way too big, then, and 2x6 sounds plenty way too big.